# Can passenger airplanes change model?

Tags: commercial-aviation, commercial-operations

Can an old airplane be upgraded, for instance changing from A320 to A320neo? Would this change its tail number?

It doesn't seem common at all, but does it ever happen?

Comment: I don't know if any modern airlines for which this is possible. The differences between the A320 and the A320neo are more than just the engines. There is, however, a project running now to re-engine the B-52 to create the B-52J, and the DC-3 has received turboprop engines and a fuselage extension to become the Super DC3. There are others

Comment: @CatchAsCatchCan: if you expand your comment a bit and add that also avionics can get update, then you've created a nice answer

Comment: As @CatchAsCatchCan mentioned. It's more than the engines. I believe the 737 max 8 incidents are a good example that it's more than swapping engines. The new engines didn't fit the plane and required Boeing to use Software tricks and a Angle-of-Attack-Sensor to make the controls flyable. And what happend because the AOA-Sensor and Software weren't fault-free is known.

Comment: @VRK - 737 MAX is flyable without any software add-ons. The issue was that in some situations it handled differently than the previous 737. This would have required simulator training for pilots making the transition, which would have been a cost to the airlines purchasing it. To avoid this the MCAS system was installed which made the MAX handle more like the original 737 in these situations, which would make it more appealing to airlines. As you mentioned there were shortcuts and poor decisions in how Boeing implemented MCAS which led to the accidents.

Answer (score 1):

With enough time and money, anything is possible. But it usually has to look economically viable to actually happen.

If you want a more efficient engine, it usually makes much more sense to buy a brand new plane than to spend money modifying one that already has thousands of hours and cycles on it. There are usually more changes than just new engines as well. Not only are you going to pay for all the work to make the conversion, the conversion will also have to be certified, which is not a fast or cheap process. Airbus already did all the work certifying a plane with the new engine so it makes more sense to just buy that one.

One notable exception is the [DC-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_DC-8), which was upgraded from the [JT3D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pratt_%26_Whitney_JT3D) to the [CFM56](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CFM56). The model had ended production so airlines couldn't just buy a new one. In addition to the fuel savings (21%, compared to about [15% on the A320 NEO](https://www.fpg-amentum.aero/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/180719-FPG-Amentum-research-A320-NEO-vs-CEO-comparison-study-1.pdf)), [the noise reduction was a major driver.](https://www.yesterdaysairlines.com/airline-history-blog/united-dc-8s-pt6-super-70s-into-the-80s) [New regulations](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-C/part-36) required all aircraft the be below a certain noise level that the turbojets and low-bypass turbofans did not meet. This meant the cost of not upgrading wasn't just extra fuel cost, but scrapping the airplanes early. Even when regulations were later relaxed, the alternative was installing [hush kits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hush_kit) that while being cheaper would also reduce performance. This resulted in 110 of the eligible 262 Super 60 series planes being converted to Super 70s with the new CFM56 engines, a rate of 42%.

The main case where engine upgrades might make sense is with military aircraft. These fleets are much smaller than commercial ones and fly much less, meaning they have much more useful life left even after decades of service and the cost of developing a new airplane is spread across much fewer aircraft. They also have different certification standards. This has resulted in several aircraft types getting upgraded engines:

- The [KC-135](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_KC-135_Stratotanker) was upgraded from the [J57](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pratt_%26_Whitney_J57) turbojets to [TF33](https://%20https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pratt_%26_Whitney_JT3D) turbofans and then later [CFM56](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CFM_International_CFM56) turbofans.
- The [C-130H](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_C-130_Hercules) is being upgraded with [new avionics](https://www.ngaus.org/sites/default/files/2022-04/FY23_FactSheet_C-130.pdf), [upgraded engines](https://www.rolls-royce.com/products-and-services/defence/aerospace/transport-tanker-patrol-and-tactical/t56-3-5-enhancement.aspx), and [new propellers](https://www.militaryaerospace.com/computers/article/14289633/electronic-control-propellers-c130)
- The [B-52](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_B-52_Stratofortress) [will upgraded](https://www.defensenews.com/air/2023/01/09/how-to-re-engine-a-b-52-and-make-a-new-bomber-fleet/) from the TF33 to the F130 ([BR700](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolls-Royce_BR700)).

And it's not just engines - sometimes major structural work is done to keep military aircraft flying:

- The [A-10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairchild_Republic_A-10_Thunderbolt_II) was [fitted with new wings.](https://www.airandspaceforces.com/boeing-starts-delivering-new-round-of-a-10-wings/)
- The [C-5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_C-5_Galaxy) was upgraded from the [TF39](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Electric_TF39) to the F138 ([CF6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Electric_CF6)) as well as having major airframe work done.

On a somewhat related note, aircraft like the A320 are offered with multiple options for engine types. In the case of the [A320 NEO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_A320neo_family), customers can choose either the [CFM LEAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CFM_International_LEAP) or [Pratt & Whitney PW1000G](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pratt_%26_Whitney_PW1000G) engines. But once the aircraft is built, even though it is certified with both engines, the configurations are different enough that an aircraft can't be changed to use a different engine type. The [787](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_787_Dreamliner) is somewhat unique in having a common interface that allows changing between the [Rolls-Royce Trent 1000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolls-Royce_Trent_1000) and [GE GEnx-1B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Electric_GEnx) engines, but it's unknown if any operator has ever taken advantage of this feature.

The closest thing to engine upgrades in the airliner market is a newer version of the same major engine type. For instance, the CFM56 engines being delivered on the last [A320s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_A320_family) before they were replaced by the NEO are more efficient than the ones delivered on the first A320s. Swapping for a newer version of the same major engine type is generally possible as the interface remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at it from the perspective of something more people are familiar with, cars.

Can you turn a 1985 BMW 320 into a 2015 BMW 320. Same generational difference. The answer is clearly no. You can retrofit a lot of the parts, but it wouldn't turn one into the other. And it's the same with aircraft. Sure, you can upgrade the avionics, put in a new interior, put in some new engines, but you still have the same old airframe structure.

And yes, that is done at times, generating some sort of hybrid that is a bit of both yet neither. The European program to upgrade their F-16A Block 15 aircraft to MLU configuration is a prime example. The old airframes were upgraded with (most of) the avionics and some other systems of the F-16C Block 50. But that didn't make them F-16Cs as the airframe differences weren't incorporated. The main spars and skin for example were not touched (doing that would be useless, it'd end up replacing every single part and effectively building F-16Cs from scratch at far greater cost (and the MLU program already cost more than just buying new F-16Cs instead! The only reason it was even considered was political idiocy where new aircraft weren't allowed for by budgets but "upgrades" were even if those upgrades cost more than new aircraft. I've seen that first hand multiple times with government agencies when working for them as a contractor).

Answer (score 0):

Normally (with the few exceptions already listed in the other answers) a new iteration of the same airplane encompasses more than just maquillage modifications rather under the skin changes that cannot be simply purchased afterward as an upgrade kit. For example the A320 NEO hasn't got only two more modern engines and a different wingtip in respect to the CEO version but also a major structural and aerodynamical redesign of the wing itself plus other improvements in the cabin.

Anyway if we don't just focus on airplane and take into consideration helicopters as well then the answer is yes. A recent example would be the Airbus H145 whose "old" 4-bladed D2 version can be updated to the new 5-bladed D3 version via an upgrade kit.